# C++ Visual Studio 2008, moving a project from 64-bit to 32-bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I've trying to use my 64-bit C++ application into a 32-bit system, but I've encountered some problems with Visual Studio 2008.

I've  just downloaded the solution on my 32-bit pc (Microsoft Windows Xp), and set Visual 
Studio settings to: Debug|Win32

The compiling phase is alright, but if I try to run the program, the system says:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\wspace4\BioTesi\BioCpp.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Somehow the system does not interpret my dll as 32-bit. I think I'm missin' some Visual Studio setting... but which?

How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a java ex eption.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up different build paths for the 32 and 64-bit dlls and exes? It's quite likely you have some 64-bit outputs overwriting the 32-bit ones.  Some things to try:

- Check out a clean workspace from your version control system so you don't have any unexpected items lying around
- Open the Configuration Manager and check that the 32-bit configuration of the solution is actually building the 32-bit versions of each project
- Use DependencyWalker which will show the .exe and .dll icons with a '64' overlay if they happen to be 64-bit